# LMS cmi.suspend_data not stored

Tags: scorm2004

I would like to store data in our ILIAS LMS with cmi.suspend_data, but the string e.g. "**L_0_0_0_0_0_0_0**" is not stored at all.

The commit I have done.

Comment: Have you tried the course in SCORM Cloud? Does it work there? http://cloud.scorm.com

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any news on this?

Comment: see http://www.ilias.de/mantis/view.php?id=16195

Answer (score 2):

Tips -

1. Check what mode you are in `cmi.mode`.  If you are in browse or review modes you will not be able to set any data.
2. Check error codes.  This may give you some tip as to either the above, or other issues reported.  That string is not over 64,000 characters and appears legal, so `var ec = lms.GetLastError();` will get you a string code, and use that to get the message `var msg = lms.GetErrorString(ec);`

Keep in mind my 'lms' API example is the resolved connection to the API_1484_11 and not an actual 'thing'.  So replace that with your local var.

I have a bookmarklet here https://www.cybercussion.com/bookmarklets/SCORM/ which may allow you some transparency finding out what mode you are in when viewing the content.

Good luck